# 'NSInputStream' does not have a member named 'setDelegate'

Tags: swift, nsstream, nsinputstream

I use `NSStreamDelegate` protocol in A `UIViewController` subclass,

And then send `setDelegate` message to a `NSInputStream`.

```
var input : NSInputStream?
var output: NSOutputStream?

func connectToSocket(host: String, port: Int) {

    NSStream.getStreamsToHostWithName(host, port: port, inputStream: &(self.input), outputStream: &(self.output)

    let str = "test"
    let data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!

    self.input?.setDelegate(self)

    self.input?.open()
    self.output?.open()

    // ...

}
```

I got a `'NSInputStream' does not have a member named 'setDelegate'` error message

Why can I use 'setDelegate'` like below document?

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
self.input?.delegate = self
```

Looks like the documentation isn't quite up to date.